# Split cells with formula in next row Excel vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to split cells if contain "," to next row i am using this formula to get data from sheet1 (=Sheet1!B3) and so on and data is in B3:AF50.
i use this vba code

```
Sub splitcells()
Dim InxSplit As Long
Dim SplitCell() As String
Dim RowCrnt As Long

 With Worksheets("Sheet2")

 RowCrnt = 3

 Do While True


  If .Cells(RowCrnt, "b").Value = "" Then
    Exit Do
  End If

  SplitCell = Split(.Cells(RowCrnt, "b").Value, ",")

  If UBound(SplitCell) > 0 Then

    .Cells(RowCrnt, "b").Value = SplitCell(0)


    For InxSplit = 1 To UBound(SplitCell)
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

      .Cells(RowCrnt, "b").Value = SplitCell(InxSplit)

      .Cells(RowCrnt, "B").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "B").Value
    Next
  End If

  RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

  Loop

End With

End Sub
```

Problem is

- I don't know how to give range(B3:Af50) in this code
- This code is not keeping my code (=Sheet1!)
- it is just copying the value before ","

my cell values are like that

B3 ABC,XYZ,KKK,LLL
i want it to split as B3 = ABC and B4 = XYZ B5 = KKK b6 = LLL

and if value in B3 is changed it should clear the cells (B4,B5,B6)splitted early and update if split required criteria ","

Have sheet like that

[image]

after split should look like that with formula intact

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No VBA is needed.

With data in *Sheet1* cell **B3**, put this in any cell of any sheet:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!$B3,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To copy **downwards**, use this formula instead:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!B$3,",",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

Comment: it is splitting it into Columns and also if value in Sheet 1 is change it is not updating sheet 2

Comment: @MuhammadKhurrumButt  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Edit#1 is working good but only in first 4 rows not covering full range B3:AF50

Comment: @MuhammadKhurrumButt i think you need to change address eg =Sheet1!B4 and so on